# Read the selected value in a dropdown choice field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read the value selected in a dropdown list using jQuery.

My HTML:

```
<select id="selectValue">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>                         
</select>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var Value = $("#selectValue option:selected").text();
  alert(Value);
});
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?
here is a snapp withresult in debbuger
[image]

Comment: Seems you have an additional `;` at the end of your `var Value = $("#selectValue option:selected").text();;` statement. Other than that code works fine for me. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcq34tL2/

Comment: @DavidR – That will not cause any harm....

Comment: Its working perfect... any console errors?

Comment: @Ma6139735 you want to take selected Value or Text? 

Also make sure that your script is placed after loading jquery as well as the select input.

Comment: i dont know whts wrong at my plce,it is not working here

Comment: @Ma6139735 Check your console for any errors.

Comment: Can you post your `<script>` tags?

Comment: means?i didn't get you

Comment: Add a selected attribute to the option that you want to be selected i.e. <option value="Yes" selected>Yes </option>

Answer (score 0):

Try `val()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var Value = $("#selectValue").val();
  alert(Value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
 $('#yourDropdownId').change(function(){
     var selectedid=$('#yourDropdownId').val();
      alert(selectedid);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var Value = $("#selectValue").find(":selected").text();
  alert(Value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 var value = $('#selectValue').val();
 var text = $('option[value="' + value + '"]', $('#selectValue')).text();
 
 console.log(value);
 console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectValue">
  <option value="YesKey">Yes</option>
  <option value="NoKey">No</option>                         
</select>

<button>get selected value</button>
```

Or you can extend jQuery:

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  valText: function() {
    return jQuery('option[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]', jQuery(this)).text();
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  console.log($('#selectValue').valText());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectValue">
  <option value="YesKey">Yes</option>
  <option value="NoKey">No</option>                         
</select>

<button>get selected value</button>
```

Comment: please try as in my working code snippet: $('option[value="' + $('#selectValue').val() + '"]', $('#selectValue')).text();

Comment: what is your browser? can i see the source code? for me the id is wrong.

Comment: browser is chrome and there is the code is as simple as i have posted in question,actually here am working with sharepoint so there i simply need a selected value of dropdown still i cal shaw you a code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123871/discussion-between-laurianti-and-ma6139735).